# How to do Linq to SQL dateTime Filter

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I I'm new to C# coming from VB and im trying to get this sql-linq query to work. It works without the `IEnumerable` date filter. But I'm not getting any error messages or syntax errors either. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? I could do it by pulling the whole table and then applying the filter, but i don't want to do that because there are too many records. I've mostly been following this tutorial to get me on the right path.

[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43025/A-LINQ-Tutorial-Mapping-Tables-to-Objects][1]

This is the code I'm currently using

```
public void getdata() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("starting");

    var STL = new STDB.reportDB(Properties.Settings.Default.dataConnString);

    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(01 / 02 / 2015);
    DateTime endDate = new DateTime(01 / 03 / 2015);

    IEnumerable<STDB.salesInvLine> lastMonthInvoiced = 
          from salesinv in STL.Sales_Inv_Lines
          where (salesinv.Shipment_Date.Year == startDate.Year
                 && salesinv.Shipment_Date.Month == startDate.Month)
          select salesinv;

    foreach (STDB.salesInvLine salesinv in lastMonthInvoiced) 
    {
        string code = salesinv.Document_No_;
        DateTime ddate = salesinv.Shipment_Date;
        Console.WriteLine(code);
    }
}
```

I think that in the `where` line all go wrong, but I really not sure.I've made sure that the field is a `DateTime` field in the database.

Other examples I found had `DateTime` defined with quotes but my Visual Studio wouldn't accept a string as a datetime like this `DateTime("01/03/2015")`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the dates this way:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015, 2, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2015, 3, 1);
```

Without the quotes you are using actually the constructor that takes an int (you are dividing) and that int means ticks!

EDITED: There is no constructor for DateTime taking [string as parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can try:

```
var myDate = Datetime.Parse("31/01/2015")
```

But bear in mind your current locale as that datetime format could means different things based on that.

Comment: Thanks man that works, Id still like to know why a quoted date wont work on my visual studio. Still waiting on the day where i stop being a moron. ;(

Comment: Edited to explain the quotes thing

Comment: You can also specify a culture or use ParseExact where you can specify the format of the date string to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(01 / 02 / 2015);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(01 / 03 / 2015);
```

lines should be

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015, 2, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime.Parse(2015, 3, 1);
```

Because, you know, `01 / 02 / 2015` and `01 / 03 / 2015` generates `0` because they are [integer divisions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html). We know them from elementary school. Both calls [`DateTime(Int64)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as `DateTime(0)` which is equal to [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Or if this is a [string date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can use;

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("01/02/2015");
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("01/03/2015");
```

Comment: Thanks for the rediculously quick reply, but when i try that, visual studio tells me "class system.String, Represents text as a series of Unicode Characters. Argument1:Cannot Convert from 'string' to 'long'"

Comment: @WouldBeNerd Sorry, fixed that.

Comment: Thanks man :), much appreciated ^^, wish i could give both of you the answer tick :/